# Draw a line as part of a QGIS model and rotate a grid accordingly

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am generating a grid based on a polygon extent. I want to be able to draw a line on the canvas  as part of the model. The line indicates the direction of the grid. My thought was to create the grid, draw a line and then calculate the azimuth of the line and then rotate the grid accordingly. Is that possible?

Comment: So, you want the model to stop midway and ask you to draw a line with two vertices on the canvas, then continue the model execution?

Comment: Yes, Please :-)

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Usually you need to input data.